# Yet another Wireguard "handshake initiated but no internet or LAN access" request for troubleshooting assistance

Tags: networking, iptables, vpn, wireguard

I had this exact configuration working for over a year until out of the blue while I was traveling a few weeks ago my wireguard connection stopped working. When I got home I tried to troubleshoot but have run out of ideas.

Home server running on 192.168.1.2, sitting behind a Unifi USG router. 51820/udp port forwarded correctly from USG to server. UFW firewall on server disabled, although there are a bunch of IP tables rules active because of a variety of docker containers running on same server. I can't make heads or tails of IP tables rules unfortunately.

wg0.conf:

```
[Interface]
# wg0
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = [redacted]

# PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp4s0 -j MASQUERADE
# PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o enp4s0 -j MASQUERADE
# These rules should NOT be necessary according to Arch Wiki and other places I have read since the wireguard "server" sits behind NAT home router. Regardless, it doesn't work with or without these iptables rules uncommented.

[Peer]
# iphone
PublicKey = [redacted]
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32
```

iphone.conf:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.2/32
PrivateKey = [redacted]
DNS = 192.168.1.1 #address of my USG router serving dns. Have also tried public DNS like 1.1.1.1 with no luck

[Peer]
PublicKey = [redacted]
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = vpn.mydomain.dev:51820 # DNS records set correctly via cloudflare (no proxying) and I know this works because I can get a handshake with the server, just no internet or LAN access.
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

ipv4 forwarding enabled:

```
xixor@192.168.1.2: ~ ➜  cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

1
```

ipv6 disabled on 192.168.1.2 server:

```
xixor@192.168.1.2: ~ ➜  sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.d/ipv6.conf

net.ipv6.conf.enp4s0.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Please let me know where else I can look to troubleshoot. Many thanks in advance!

Edit - additional troubleshooting steps tried unsuccessfully since original post -

I completely stopped all docker containers and then the docker service itself, then flushed all iptables rules while still ensuring all forwarded packets accepted:

```
#!/bin/sh
ipt="/sbin/iptables"

$ipt -P INPUT ACCEPT 
$ipt -P FORWARD ACCEPT 
$ipt -P OUTPUT ACCEPT 
$ipt -F 
$ipt -X 
$ipt -t nat -F 
$ipt -t nat -X 
$ipt -t mangle -F 
$ipt -t mangle -X 
$ipt -t raw -F 
$ipt -t raw -X
```

Check to see IPv4 iptables after flush:

```
sudo iptables -L -v -n

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 3111 packets, 355K bytes)

pkts bytes target prot opt in out source destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes) pkts bytes target prot opt in out source destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2087 packets, 156K bytes) pkts bytes target prot opt in out source destination
```

Then tried the wireguard tunnel and still same situation - handshake but no internet or LAN connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

The handshake works and bytes are transferred (with `PersistentKeepalive = 25` in the configuration). But the connection silently fails with a timeout on anything you try to send over the connection.

If that is your problem, then it is very **important to realize** that when the Address/AllowedIPs or the PrivateKey/PublicKey configuration does not match between both peers, the connection will indeed simply timeout, even though the handshake could still work (according to `wg show`).

Fix the problem by:

- Ensuring that the `Address` entry of A's Interface-section is within the range of the `AllowedIPs` entry of B's Peer-section.
- Ensuring that `wg pubkey <<<"<PrivateKey of A's Interface-section"` matches the `PublicKey` entry of B`s Peer-section.

And vice versa (swap A and B).

Then you must reset the interfaces on both peers using (where wg0 is the name of your interface):

```
wg-quick down wg0
wg-quick up wg0
```

Note that `wg syncconf wg0 <(wg-quick strip wg0)` is not enough if you changed `Address`.

---

In your specific case, you might change `Address = 10.0.0.1/24` to `Address = 10.0.0.1/32` or simply `Address = 10.0.0.1`. I don't think you're supposed to set an IP-range in the `Address` entry, that is only for AllowedIPs in order to allow multiple IP addresses.